# Select next free number between range of numbers from Mysql table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write query which select next free number from table where number should be between 2000 and 2500

I have table:

```
|   id  | number  |
|-------|---------|
| 1     | 1000    |
| 2     | 1001    |
| 3     | 3000    |
```

I want to get 2001

I have sql :

```
SELECT number + 1 next_number
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS( 
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE number = t.number + 1)
ORDER BY number LIMIT 1
```

And it returns me 1002.

I tried:

```
SELECT number + 1 next_number
FROM table t
WHERE number + 1 BETWEEN 2000 AND 2500
AND NOT EXISTS( 
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE number = t.number + 1)
ORDER BY number LIMIT 1
```

And got nothing.

However if I will add number 2000 into table it will return 2001.

How to fix this query to return 2001 even if  there is not number 2000 in table?

Comment: *How to fix this query to return 2001 even if there is not number 2000 in table?* Convert your verbal condition "where number should be between 2000 and 2500" to programming condition `WHERE number BETWEEN 2000 + 1 AND 2500`. "BETWEEN" means "not less then lower bound and not greater than upper bound".

Comment: WHERE number BETWEEN 2000 + 1 AND 2500 didn't work also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT MIN(`number`) + 1 result
FROM ( SELECT `number`
       FROM test
       WHERE `number` BETWEEN @from AND @till
       UNION 
       SELECT @from ) tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM test
                   WHERE `number` = tmp.`number` + 1 )
HAVING result <= @till;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ed4c2178dce080c5a81edddc00dcbc89)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you should check for null result

```
select next_number from (
    SELECT ifnull(number + 1,2001) next_number
    FROM table t
    WHERE number + 1 BETWEEN 2000 AND 2500
    UNION 
    SELECT ifnull(number + 1,2001)
) t
```

ORDER BY next_number LIMIT 1

Comment: It returned nothing

Comment: Same : Found rows: 0